# how can I move my webpage to another tab?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

basically what i want to do is the move my pages "Feature Article" from View tab to Browse Tab but i got no idea to do it although i already google for whole Day. what should i do now inorder to move it to Browse Tab?

[image: My Screen shot]

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
<meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
<script type="text/javascript">
```

the code above is part of my code but i not sure this is helpful or not, or maybe i dont really need to look the code at all

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Why do you want to move a page to the "Browse" tab? Do you understand what it does? Where exactly on the "Browse" tab should a page show? The "Browse" tab normally just shows the breadcrumb nav and a drop-down to change the current view (where applicable). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @teylyn because the page is my main pages, supposingly the page is together with Browse Tab, but dont know y it move to View tab, this make me suffer :(